# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor de un input en tiempo real?

Tags: angular, ionic, funciones, input, real-time

Hola y muchas gracias por su colaboración, me encuentro ante la necesidad de obtener el valor de un input en tiempo real, osea necesito tener el valor del input a la misma vez que el usuario lo esta escribiendo.
Ahora mismo tengo el siguiente input y la siguiente función:

**imput:**

```
<ion-input type="password" placeholder="Escriba aqui" (change)=checkStrenght(actualPass) [(ngModel)]="actualPass"></ion-input>
```

**función:**

```
  checkStrenght(actualPass) {
    console.log(actualPass);
    console.log(actualPass.length);
    if (actualPass.length >= 1 && actualPass.length <= 6) {
      this.strenght = 1;
    }
    if (actualPass.length >= 7 && actualPass.length <= 8) {
      this.strenght = 2;
    }
    if (actualPass.length >= 9) {
      this.strenght = 3;
    }
  }
```

Problema de mi código: La función se ejecuta cuando el usuario termina de escribir en el input.

Solución esperada: cada vez que el usuario escriba o elimine un caracter del input se ejecutara la función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el evento `change` por `keyup`

```
(keyup)=checkStrenght(actualPass)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta me ha ayudado mucho!!